# Why can we only find the asymptotic expression of the solution of the first implicit function?

Tags: equation-solving, asymptotics

Here are three implicit function equations

```
AsymptoticSolve[(a*y^2 + Sin[x])^2 == x, y, {x, 1, 3}]
AsymptoticSolve[(a*Sin[y]^2 + Sin[x])^2 == x, y, {x, 1, 3}]
AsymptoticSolve[(a*y^2 + Sin[x*y])^2 == x, y, {x, 1, 3}]
```

Why can we only find the asymptotic expression of the solution of the first implicit function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AsymptoticSolve` command works with the result of the `Solve` command. Let us consider these results.

2. `Solve[(a*Sin[y]^2 + Sin[x])^2 == x, y]`
   results in 8 expressions of the form `y->ConditionalExpression` which are infinitely valued because of terms `2 \[Pi] C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers` . I think this circumstance makes difficulties. The following works as a workaround.

   `Table[Series[y /. Solve[(a*Sin[y]^2 + Sin[x])^2 ==x,y][[j]],{x, 1, 3}],{j, 1, 8}]`
3. No comment in view of

   `Solve[(a*y^2 + Sin[x*y])^2 == x, y]`

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

Comment: For (2), one may also pick a particular solution as an initial condition for `y`: for example, `AsymptoticSolve[(a*Sin[y]^2 + Sin[x])^2 == x, {y, 
  1/2 ArcCos[(-2 + a + 2 Sin[1])/a]}, {x, 1, 3}]` (+1)